# Slide expand animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a simple list view listing results title in android. Upon click of each item, I would like it to slide down expand and show the content. Is there an easy way to do this in android?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Examples:

1. [Steps to implement ExpandableListView in android](http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html)
2. [ExpandableListView on Android](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html)